# Flutter - Duplicate Widgets with an Action

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to replicate my widgets with an action in app.

Example :  I have an Row, and this row create duplicate elements with directions differents

```
controller.turns.value == 1 ?
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: controller.rotation.value,
                child: Image(
                  image: const AssetImage('reference.png'),
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8) *
                      controller.size.value,
                  width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8) *
                      controller.size.value,
                ),
              ),
            )
```

when turns.value == 2, i need 2 Containers, and with 3 == 3, 4 == 4, 5 == 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function like this:

```dart
List<Widget> getWidgets(int count) => List.generate(count, (_) => yourWidget);
```

and use it like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: getWidgets(4),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `list<Widget>` calls containers. and make for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < controller.turns.value; i++) {

            containers.add(Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: controller.rotation.value,
                child: Image(
                  image: const AssetImage('reference.png'),
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8) *
                      controller.size.value,
                  width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8) *
                      controller.size.value,
                ),
              ),
            ),)
          }
```

then use containers in listview or column widget.